# Pagination in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm pretty new to Magento, and have been following the base theme so far along, but I am having problems with catalog pagination.

At the moment I'm having problems getting the "page/html_pager" block to display.

So, my catalog.xml has this for both anchor and non-anchor categories:

```
<reference name="content"> 
    <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
               <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                      <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager" />
                </block>
         </block>
    </block>
</reference>
```

My toolbar.phtml has the corresponding code:

`<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>`

and my default/template/page/html/pager.phtml just contains some test code along the lines of:
`<h1>Test</h1>`

At first I thought it might be because there weren't multiple pages, so I added some products and set the both the grid and the list views to show a maximum of 1 per page, and the item count reflects this:
`Showing 1 of 11 items`

Doing a `var_dump` on the `$this->getPagerHtml()` returns an empty string, and using the template path hints indicates it doesn't even seem to load the block - yet it loads it's parent block.

Copying the code directly from the base design package doesn't work, yet switching to that package it does.

So, what am I missing? Or doing wrong? I've run out of ideas as to what it could be.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved:

Adding
`<action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>`

After the product_list_toolbar block appeared to fix this issue.

Magento's documentation is a little thin on the ground with this so I'm unsure as to why
`<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">`

requires it's name set again with an action tag, but it does.

If anyone can explain this, I'd love to understand it.

Comment: Great find, I too was experiencing this issue when using a local.xml and your solution restored the pagination perfectly. Really bizarre, would love to hear an explanation of why this was required also. Thanks for sharing your solution fin.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance that it's being overridden by a different .xml file in layout?

You could always remove all the .xml files in the layout directory and bring them back in one by one and see if the pagination toolbar disappears, whilst making sure cache is turned off.

After that, rename the template directory catalog to ~catalog and let it pick up the base catalog directory and see if it's actually the .phtml files causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks so much, I've narrowed it down to being somehow layout related thing by prefixing a ~ to the layout folder. But when I attempt it with just my catalog.xml file, I get a blank output. It doesn't appear to like using the default catalog.xml and there's no errors/exceptions logged. I'll keep trying.

Comment: Ahh, it appears it's giving me a blank output because the base catalog.xml didn't set the root template. I've added that and the pagination is appearing using that. So it's definitely an issue with my catalog.xml. Now to find out why.